# Create separately numpy arrays from pandas dataframe columns

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I would like to create automatically in Python n of numpy arrays from my pandas dataframe columns. I can do this manually using for example:

```
numpy_array_1 = data_frame.column_1.values
numpy_array_2 = data_frame.column_2.values
...
numpy_array_n = data_frame.column_n.values
```

But I can not know how I should write code to create those arrays automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use a `for` and loop through it. Remember that using `(list(data_frame))` returns a list of the column names in the dataframe:

```
np_array = []
for i in list(data_frame):
    np_array.append(data_frame[i].values)
```

The expected output is a list that contains sublists of values. Where each sublist matches the position of the columns in the dataframe. Therefore you can either make a dictionary, or a tuple out of it. Dictionary example:

```
np_array_dict = {}
for i in list(data_frame):
    np_array_dict[i] = data_frame[i].values
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. A solution with a dictionary is perfect for my needs.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose we have a simple df:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"0":[1,2], "1":[3,4]})
df 
   0  1
0  1  3
1  2  4
```

Then you can run:

```
for (key,value) in df.to_dict("list").items():
    exec("numpy_array_{} = np.array({})".format(key, value))
```

You'll get:

```
numpy_array_0
array([1, 2])

numpy_array_1
array([3, 4])
```

and so on.

Alternatively:

```
for col in list(df):
    exec("numpy_array_{} = df[str({})].values".format(col,col))
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I will be use this solution to another case.

Answer (score 0):

You can get matrix of all dataframe rows and columns values as simple as df.values
Do you really need distinct array for each column?

Comment: No, it will be enough if I will be having arrays in one array as in the example of @Celius Stingher

Answer (score 0):

This can be done without using loops:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"0":[1,2], "1":[3,4], "2":[5,6]})
print(df)

   0  1  2
0  1  3  5
1  2  4  6
```

and then:

```
[*np.transpose(df.values)]
```

results in:

```
[array([1, 2]), array([3, 4]), array([5, 6])]
```

and if a dictionary is desired one just needs to proceed as follows:

```
dict(zip(range(df.shape[1]), [*np.transpose(df.values)]))
```

which gives:

```
{0: array([1, 2]), 1: array([3, 4]), 2: array([5, 6])}
```